# UIViewController not passing data between views

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, ios7

I'm trying to pass some data between UIViewControllers in a storyboard. I have some code below to pass the data. Whne I log the string that i'm saving on the original screen it's fine, but when I go to the `UIDetailViewController` the go is returning `(null)`. What's my issue??

Original View Controller:

```
 -(void)tableView:(UITableView *) tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    if (tableView==_countryTableView) {
        if (indexPath.section==0) {
            AthleteDataTransfer *dataTransfer = [[AthleteDataTransfer alloc] init];
            dataTransfer.name=@"Yo";
            dataTransfer.dob=@"01/01/2000";
            dataTransfer.description=@"I am awesome";
            dataTransfer.hometown=@"Launy";

            NSLog(@"%@", dataTransfer.name);

            [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"showDetail" sender:self];

        }

    }
}
```

Detail View Controller:

```
AthleteDataTransfer *dataTransfer = [[AthleteDataTransfer alloc] init];
        _name.text=dataTransfer.name;
        dataTransfer.dob=_dob.text;
        dataTransfer.description=_description.text;
        dataTransfer.hometown=_hometown.text;

        NSLog(@"%@", dataTransfer.name);
```

Comment: When you go to your Detail View Controller from your tableview's didselect method. What you get in NSLog on your Detail View Controller's viewDidLoad?

Comment: I get a (null) message

Comment: Have you defined properties for those objects and synthesized them?

Comment: Have you created your labels are IBOutlet or you are allocating them on viewdidload method?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use `prepareForSegue` method to accomplish this.
and if you have more than one segues from this ViewController you can use   `segue.Identifier` to distinguish

```
-(void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{

    if(segue.identifier==@"yoursegueidentitifer")
     {
       DetailedViewController *detailController = [segue destinationViewController];
       detailController.nameoftextview.text =self.textViewName.text;
    }
}
```

Comment: Cheers, what do I do if i'm wanting to trigger the segue from a tableView and have unique pieces of data for each row??

Comment: Declare some variables  to save data in your viewController .h  when a table row got selected in in tableView: selectrowForIndexPath: save data in these variables and when you are performing segue in prepareForSegue:   sender: you can access data from these variables and send them along with segue to your destination view

Answer (score 5):

Insted of passing data in tableViews **didSelectRowAtIndexPath**, pass the data in **prepareForSegue** method.

Like this:

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {
    if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"showDetail"]) {
        AthleteDataTransfer *dataTransfer = (AthleteDataTransfer *)[segue destinationViewController];
        dataTransfer.name=@"Yo";
        dataTransfer.dob=@"01/01/2000";
        dataTransfer.description=@"I am awesome";
        dataTransfer.hometown=@"Launy";
    }
}
```

Comment: Still returning (null)

Comment: you do not need to re-allocate the object in detail view controller, are you allocating again ?

Comment: when you write the statement,
AthleteDataTransfer *dataTransfer = [[AthleteDataTransfer alloc] init];
It actually generate a new object of AthleteDataTransfer, instead of that try to use the passed object.

Answer (score 3):

As suggested in other answers out here you should pass data in the `prepareForSegue` method. I'am not going to repeat the same code here. I wanted point out one thing that you dont want to create the `DetailViewController` again in the detailViewController like below

```
AthleteDataTransfer *dataTransfer = [[AthleteDataTransfer alloc] init]; //  This is wrong and not required at all 
NSLog(@"%@", dataTransfer.name);
```

Instead you should use `self` to refer the current controller

```
NSLog(@"%@", self.name); // This would be enough
```

Answer (score 1):

For posting the text data to your destination View Controller, you can use the `prepareForSegue` method like this.

```
-(void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    DestinationViewController *destController = [segue destinationViewController];
    destController._yourTextView.text == _yourText.text;
    }
}
```

Here, DesctinationViewController is the controller **to** which you want to pass the values and in the next step, you assign the values by using its object and the properties declared on that controller.

Since you are using `performSegueWithIdentifier`, this will automatically call `prepareForSegue` after `performSegueWithIdentifier` is executed which will show up your destination View Controller.